# Recurrence relation for total number of ways to subset sum

Tags: algorithm, recursion, recurrence, subset-sum

I am trying to find out total number of ways to reach a target in subset sum problem. Below is my approach.

Let DP[i, j] be 1 if sum of 'j' elements sum up to 'i' else it is 0 where 'a' be the input. So,

```
DP[i, j] = DP[i, j-1] + DP[i - a[j], j-1]
```

For input [10, 13, 15, 18, 20, 15] and target = 30
; we are looking for DP[30, 6] as the answer.

I am able to get it working with recursion (http://ideone.com/0sHhDL) but i need to do it with DP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a recursive function written, all we need to add to make it efficient is to cache the return values.  The modification is: Before making a recursive call, check that the computation with those arguments was not already done.

```c
int NMAX = 100;
int cache[NMAX][NMAX];
int answer;
// Returns true if there is a subset of set[] with sun equal to given sum
int isSubsetSum(int set[], int n, int sum)
{

    // Base Cases
    if (sum == 0) {
        answer++;
        return 0; //return false here as we are after all the sums
    }
    if (n == 0 && sum != 0)
        return 0;

    if(cache[n][sum] == -1) {

        // If last element is greater than sum, then ignore it
        if (set[n-1] > sum)
            return isSubsetSum(set, n-1, sum);

        /* else, check if sum can be obtained by any of the following
           (a) including the last element
           (b) excluding the last element   */
        cache[n][sum] = isSubsetSum(set, n-1, sum) || isSubsetSum(set, n-1, sum-set[n-1]);
    }
    return cache[n][sum];
}

// Driver program to test above function
int main()
{
    int set[] = {3, 34, 4, 12, 5, 2};
    int sum = 9;
    int n = sizeof(set)/sizeof(set[0]);
    for(int i=0; i<NMAX; i++) for(int j=0; j<NMAX; j++)
        cache[i][j] = -1;
    isSubsetSum(set, n, sum);
    printf("total %d\n", answer);
    return 0;
}
```

In the code, the line

```
cache[n][sum] = isSubsetSum(set, n-1, sum) || isSubsetSum(set, n-1, sum-set[n-1]);
```

is equivalent to the recursive formula

```
DP[i, j] = DP[i, j-1] + DP[i - a[j], j-1]
```

The difference is that one is top-bottom, the other is bottom-top.

Comment: yes, substitute `i` and `j` and `a`, by `sum`, `n`, and `set`, and the two lines are identical.